# How can we generate a sequence of numbers from Polynomial regression curve?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, computer-science

I miss a part of my dataset, which is the position of the tennis ball in the video for each frame. The missing part is when the player hits the ball, and the ball goes up and comes down to the second player taking a curve shape.
I have create the curve using polynomial regression method, as shown in the image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFWqn.png)
The curve presents the ten points before missing the data and ten points after.
Now, How can we generate a sequence of points, which is the missing datase, from the curve that I have created using python?!

The missing data points:

([1189,1188, 1186,1187,1184,1183,1182,1181,1181,1181[missing data]908,906,901,900,898,893,888,883,878,879])
([221,216,213,212,209,205,200,195,195,195[missing data]212,222,235,235,249,263,276,292,303,303])

This is the Code that I use to create the curve:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([1189,1188, 1186,1187,1184,1183,1182,1181,1181,1181,908,906,901,900,898,893,888,883,878,879])
y = np.array([221,216,213,212,209,205,200,195,195,195,212,222,235,235,249,263,276,292,303,303])

model = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x,y,3))
line = np.linspace(np.min(x), np.max(x), num=100)
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(line, model(line))
plt.show()
```

Comment: It seems that the image is missing.

Comment: Yes. Sorry just add it.

Answer (score 0):

Your model was obtained using `np.polyfit`:

```
fitted_parameters = np.polyfit(x,y,3)
```

You can use `np.polyval` to make a prediction:

```
x = 1050
prediction = np.polyval(fitted_parameters, x)
# The prediction value for x = 1050 is y = 8.64
```

So it is just a matter of using `np.linspace` to obtain an evenly distributed set of x values and use `np.polyval` to obtain the curve (y values that are missing).

Comment: That was very helpful. I appreciate it :)